# Initiate call from webview programmatically

Tags: android, mobile-website, phone-call

I have the following problem:

I am working on an Android application where at some point I load a webview with content from the internet. The HTML and javascript code of the webview includes the appropriate tag (`<a href="tel:0863274XX"> blablabla </a>`) in order to perform the call through the application by launching the appropriate app of my android phone.

Unfortunately, when I click on the image that has the a href, the browser gives an error by saying that the "web page is not available" and it can't load the tel:0863274XX element.

The headers of the loaded webview also include (which I don't really know the effect):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```

What am I doing wrong ? What should I look for ?
I have also tried to use the whole phone number (with country and area code) and the "call" tag instead of the "tel" but with no success.

Any ideas and comments are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to use the solution provided here:

[Android WebView "tel:" links show web page not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338305/android-webview-tel-links-show-web-page-not-found)

There they basically start an ACTION_DIAL intent. You can replace it by ACTION_CALL if you include the appropriate permission in your AndroidManifest.xml, but be warned that this is extremely dangerous for your users if your WebView does show web pages which are not controlled by your app!