# Android WebView “tel:” & "mailto:"links show web page not found

Tags: android, http, webview, mailto, tel

I am trying to open **tel:** & **mailto:** link from `webview`, and receive the following message:

```
Web Page Not Found tel:0000000000
```

The only link that works is "http:" and "https"

Can anyone help me?

```
     private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
    {
        webview.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int KeyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((KeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack())
    {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(KeyCode, event);
}

public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url) {
    if (url.startsWith("tel:")) { 
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(url)); 
            startActivity(intent); 
    }else if(url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") || url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
        webview.loadUrl(url);
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Hey Robert, this may help you out:[Android WebView “tel:” links show web page not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338305/android-webview-tel-links-show-web-page-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

Do not call loadUrl(url);

```
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {

     if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(url));
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
    else{
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
        return true; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to return **false** to the tel: and mailto: if and else if branches.

This should work.

Comment: @ Tim Messerschmidt i updated the code, only the "http" links are working, any suggestions?

Comment: You handle the Intent for tel: wrong - it must look like this: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));

Comment: @ Tim Messerschmidt Unfortunately even this solution does not work

Comment: You must return true if you handle the intent and false if not.