# Using tel: Hyperlinks on Android < 4 alternative?

Tags: javascript, android, html, tel

I have an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jampez.no) which gives normal landline numbers for UK 08 numbers.

Currently this is a web page shown in the app, when the user finds the number they want and click on the green phone icon. I'm using the following JavaScript to force then force a tel: link with the number to bring up the dailer.

```
document.location.href = 'tel:'+number;//push browser to call number
```

This method works fine for all newer android 4.0 and above as far as i can see. But when i use my old Orange San Francisco Phone (android 2.3) it doesnt bring the dailer. Instead it just attempts to open a new page with tel:01xxxxxxxx as the URL which in turn displays a web page not available message.

I assume this is because tel: is part of HTML5 which is why it's not working. Is there any alternative that would work on all versions?

Comment: Are you wrapping this in a `webview` - aka do you have access to the native Android code as well?

Comment: yes it's in a webview, just displays my web page like an iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tel:` is preferred - since the 1990's. `callto:` may work better for some devices. See also: [How to mark-up phone numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164004/how-to-mark-up-phone-numbers)

**EDIT**

Since you have the page running inside an Android WebView, you can handle this error with the hack (also described at [Android WebView "tel:" links show web page not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338305/android-webview-tel-links-show-web-page-not-found)):

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
    @Override  
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {  
        if (url.startsWith("tel:")) { 
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)); 
            startActivity(intent); 
        }
        else if(url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;  
    }  
}
```

For which you may need the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: I've tried callto: as well and it still produces the same results i'm afraid

Comment: right, I shall try this as soon as I get home from work and let you know, Thanks in advance though

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to make a difference :/

Comment: @jampez77, just to make sure we're on the same page, I edited my post with the code to use. Can you verify this does not work?

Comment: Just tried the new code and it work prefectly, thank you so much :)