# Android Webview tel: link ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: android, webview, hyperlink, tel

I want to use tel: links in my website under webview, but when i click it i got this error message: ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME.

I dont know what is the problem, everything is working fine, except this special link.

Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webView.loadUrl("http://mywebsite.com");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if( URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(url) ) {
            return false;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity( intent );
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
                    webView.loadUrl("javascript:open_menu()");
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338305/android-webview-tel-links-show-web-page-not-found

Comment: i copied the public boolen from here...(http://stackoverflow.com/a/5545463/6442546)

Answer (score 4):

Finally i solved the problem!

Here is the good code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.mywebpage.com");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if( URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(url) ) {
                return false;
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity( intent );
            return true;
        }

    });
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:open_menu()");
            return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


}
```

Comment: Please post the changes you made not the whole code

Comment: Had to diff the 2 code blocks, but it looks like the solution is in the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` implementation. In the original code, it was implemented as a function on the Activity, not overriding the default function in the WebViewClient.